# Installing node modules xml-stream

Tags: node.js, xmlnode, node-modules

[image]

I have a problem installing the node modules xml-stream. It says,  "cannot open include file 'stdint.h' : no such file or directory." I do not know where to look for that file. Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to install [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-express) first